# How to start capture video automaticlly, when the app is starting

Tags: android, android-camera

I want to show a camera preview and start capture immediately when the preview is ready (base on [camera2 API](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/camera2/package-summary.html))

To do this simple, I build a sample app that should start capture video automatically when the preview is ready based on [Google camera2Video example](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-Camera2Video) and modify it according my needs.

Here is my code for `OnCreate` method:

```
if (null == savedInstanceState) {
    getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.container, camera2VideoFragment)
            .commit();
}

Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        while (!camera2VideoFragment.isCameraReady) {
            try {
                Log.d("camera status", String.valueOf(camera2VideoFragment.isCameraReady));
                Thread.sleep(500);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        camera2VideoFragment.captureVideo();
    }
};
runnable.run();
```

When in [`Camera2VideoFragment` class](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-Camera2Video/blob/master/Application/src/main/java/com/example/android/camera2video/Camera2VideoFragment.java) I add public static Boolean variable initlize to false and modify it to true when the camera is ready, using `CameraDevice.StateCallback`, like this:

```
private CameraDevice.StateCallback mStateCallback = new CameraDevice.StateCallback() {
@Override
public void onOpened(CameraDevice cameraDevice) {
    mCameraDevice = cameraDevice;
    startPreview();
    mCameraOpenCloseLock.release();

    isCameraReady = true; // Setting the Boolean to true here

    if (null != mTextureView) {
        configureTransform(mTextureView.getWidth(), mTextureView.getHeight());
    }
}
```

**The problem**, `isCameraReady` stay false forever when I'm using the while check (* If I start capture after button event the value is true and all works fine)

**The question:** How can I know when the preview is ready and *start capture video* automatically, *without pressing on any button?* (clicking the button will be to stop the record, not to start it)

### Edit

Below is `Camera2VideoFragment` relevant code, you can find the full code [here](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-Camera2Video/blob/master/Application/src/main/java/com/example/android/camera2video/Camera2VideoFragment.java).

```
public class Camera2VideoFragment extends Fragment
        implements FragmentCompat.OnRequestPermissionsResultCallback {

    private static final SparseIntArray ORIENTATIONS = new SparseIntArray();

    private static final String TAG = "Camera2VideoFragment";
    private static final int REQUEST_VIDEO_PERMISSIONS = 1;
    private static final String FRAGMENT_DIALOG = "dialog";

    static {
        ORIENTATIONS.append(Surface.ROTATION_0, 90);
        ORIENTATIONS.append(Surface.ROTATION_90, 0);
        ORIENTATIONS.append(Surface.ROTATION_180, 270);
        ORIENTATIONS.append(Surface.ROTATION_270, 180);
    }

    private AutoFitTextureView mTextureView;
    private CameraDevice mCameraDevice;
    private CameraCaptureSession mPreviewSession;
    private TextureView.SurfaceTextureListener mSurfaceTextureListener
            = new TextureView.SurfaceTextureListener() {

        @Override
        public void onSurfaceTextureAvailable(SurfaceTexture surfaceTexture,
                                              int width, int height) {
            openCamera(width, height);
        }
        @Override
        public void onSurfaceTextureSizeChanged(SurfaceTexture surfaceTexture,
                                                int width, int height) {
            configureTransform(width, height);
        }
        @Override
        public boolean onSurfaceTextureDestroyed(SurfaceTexture surfaceTexture) {
            return true;
        }
        @Override
        public void onSurfaceTextureUpdated(SurfaceTexture surfaceTexture) {
        }
    };

    private Size mPreviewSize;
    private Size mVideoSize;
    private CaptureRequest.Builder mPreviewBuilder;
    private MediaRecorder mMediaRecorder;
    private static boolean mIsRecordingVideo;
    private HandlerThread mBackgroundThread;
    private Handler mBackgroundHandler;
    private Semaphore mCameraOpenCloseLock = new Semaphore(1);

    public static Boolean isCameraReady = false;    // I add this variable in order to found when can I start recording

    private CameraDevice.StateCallback mStateCallback = new CameraDevice.StateCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onOpened(CameraDevice cameraDevice) {
            mCameraDevice = cameraDevice;
            startPreview();
            mCameraOpenCloseLock.release();

            isCameraReady = true;                   // Here I set the Boolean to true

            if (null != mTextureView) {
                configureTransform(mTextureView.getWidth(), mTextureView.getHeight());
            }
        }
        @Override
        public void onDisconnected(CameraDevice cameraDevice) {
            mCameraOpenCloseLock.release();
            cameraDevice.close();
            mCameraDevice = null;
            isCameraReady = false;
        }
        @Override
        public void onError(CameraDevice cameraDevice, int error) {
            mCameraOpenCloseLock.release();
            cameraDevice.close();
            mCameraDevice = null;
            Activity activity = getActivity();
            if (null != activity) {
                activity.finish();
            }
            isCameraReady = false;
        }
    };

    public void captureVideo()
    {
        if (mIsRecordingVideo) {
            stopRecordingVideo();
        } else {
            startRecordingVideo();
        }
    }

    private void startBackgroundThread() {
        mBackgroundThread = new HandlerThread("CameraBackground");
        mBackgroundThread.start();
        mBackgroundHandler = new Handler(mBackgroundThread.getLooper());
    }

    private void stopBackgroundThread() {
        mBackgroundThread.quitSafely();
        try {
            mBackgroundThread.join();
            mBackgroundThread = null;
            mBackgroundHandler = null;
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private void openCamera(int width, int height) {
        if (!hasPermissionsGranted(VIDEO_PERMISSIONS)) {
            requestVideoPermissions();
            return;
        }
        final Activity activity = getActivity();
        if (null == activity || activity.isFinishing()) {
            return;
        }
        CameraManager manager = (CameraManager) activity.getSystemService(Context.CAMERA_SERVICE);
        try {
            Log.d(TAG, "tryAcquire");
            if (!mCameraOpenCloseLock.tryAcquire(2500, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)) {
                throw new RuntimeException("Time out waiting to lock camera opening.");
            }
            String cameraId = manager.getCameraIdList()[0];

            // Choose the sizes for camera preview and video recording
            CameraCharacteristics characteristics = manager.getCameraCharacteristics(cameraId);
            StreamConfigurationMap map = characteristics
                    .get(CameraCharacteristics.SCALER_STREAM_CONFIGURATION_MAP);
            mVideoSize = chooseVideoSize(map.getOutputSizes(MediaRecorder.class));
            mPreviewSize = chooseOptimalSize(map.getOutputSizes(SurfaceTexture.class),
                    width, height, mVideoSize);

            int orientation = getResources().getConfiguration().orientation;
            if (orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {
                mTextureView.setAspectRatio(mPreviewSize.getWidth(), mPreviewSize.getHeight());
            } else {
                mTextureView.setAspectRatio(mPreviewSize.getHeight(), mPreviewSize.getWidth());
            }
            configureTransform(width, height);
            mMediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder();
            manager.openCamera(cameraId, mStateCallback, null);
        } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
            Toast.makeText(activity, "Cannot access the camera.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            activity.finish();
        } catch (NullPointerException e) {
            // Currently an NPE is thrown when the Camera2API is used but not supported on the
            // device this code runs.
            ErrorDialog.newInstance(getString(R.string.camera_error))
                    .show(getChildFragmentManager(), FRAGMENT_DIALOG);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Interrupted while trying to lock camera opening.");
        }
    }

    private void startPreview() {
        if (null == mCameraDevice || !mTextureView.isAvailable() || null == mPreviewSize) {
            return;
        }
        try {
            setUpMediaRecorder();
            SurfaceTexture texture = mTextureView.getSurfaceTexture();
            assert texture != null;
            texture.setDefaultBufferSize(mPreviewSize.getWidth(), mPreviewSize.getHeight());
            mPreviewBuilder = mCameraDevice.createCaptureRequest(CameraDevice.TEMPLATE_RECORD);
            List<Surface> surfaces = new ArrayList<Surface>();

            Surface previewSurface = new Surface(texture);
            surfaces.add(previewSurface);
            mPreviewBuilder.addTarget(previewSurface);

            Surface recorderSurface = mMediaRecorder.getSurface();
            surfaces.add(recorderSurface);
            mPreviewBuilder.addTarget(recorderSurface);

            mCameraDevice.createCaptureSession(surfaces, new CameraCaptureSession.StateCallback()
            {
                @Override
                public void onConfigured(CameraCaptureSession cameraCaptureSession) {
                    mPreviewSession = cameraCaptureSession;
                    updatePreview();
                }
                @Override
                public void onConfigureFailed(CameraCaptureSession cameraCaptureSession) {
                    Activity activity = getActivity();
                    if (null != activity) {
                        Toast.makeText(activity, "Failed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }
            }, mBackgroundHandler);
            isCameraReady = true;
        } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private void updatePreview() {
        if (null == mCameraDevice) {
            return;
        }
        try {
            setUpCaptureRequestBuilder(mPreviewBuilder);
            HandlerThread thread = new HandlerThread("CameraPreview");
            thread.start();
            mPreviewSession.setRepeatingRequest(mPreviewBuilder.build(), null, mBackgroundHandler);
        } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private void setUpCaptureRequestBuilder(CaptureRequest.Builder builder) {
        builder.set(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_MODE, CameraMetadata.CONTROL_MODE_AUTO);
    }

    private void configureTransform(int viewWidth, int viewHeight) {
        Activity activity = getActivity();
        if (null == mTextureView || null == mPreviewSize || null == activity) {
            return;
        }
        int rotation = activity.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getRotation();
        Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
        RectF viewRect = new RectF(0, 0, viewWidth, viewHeight);
        RectF bufferRect = new RectF(0, 0, mPreviewSize.getHeight(), mPreviewSize.getWidth());
        float centerX = viewRect.centerX();
        float centerY = viewRect.centerY();
        if (Surface.ROTATION_90 == rotation || Surface.ROTATION_270 == rotation) {
            bufferRect.offset(centerX - bufferRect.centerX(), centerY - bufferRect.centerY());
            matrix.setRectToRect(viewRect, bufferRect, Matrix.ScaleToFit.FILL);
            float scale = Math.max(
                    (float) viewHeight / mPreviewSize.getHeight(),
                    (float) viewWidth / mPreviewSize.getWidth());
            matrix.postScale(scale, scale, centerX, centerY);
            matrix.postRotate(90 * (rotation - 2), centerX, centerY);
        }
        mTextureView.setTransform(matrix);
    }

    private void setUpMediaRecorder() throws IOException {
        final Activity activity = getActivity();
        if (null == activity) {
            return;
        }
        mMediaRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
        mMediaRecorder.setVideoSource(MediaRecorder.VideoSource.SURFACE);
        mMediaRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.MPEG_4);
        mMediaRecorder.setOutputFile(getVideoFile(activity).getAbsolutePath());
        mMediaRecorder.setVideoEncodingBitRate(10000000);
        mMediaRecorder.setVideoFrameRate(30);
        mMediaRecorder.setVideoSize(mVideoSize.getWidth(), mVideoSize.getHeight());
        mMediaRecorder.setVideoEncoder(MediaRecorder.VideoEncoder.H264);
        mMediaRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AAC);
        int rotation = activity.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getRotation();
        int orientation = ORIENTATIONS.get(rotation);
        mMediaRecorder.setOrientationHint(orientation);
        mMediaRecorder.prepare();
    }

    private void startRecordingVideo() {
        try {
            mIsRecordingVideo = true;
            mMediaRecorder.start();
        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private void stopRecordingVideo() {
        mIsRecordingVideo = false;
        mMediaRecorder.stop();
        mMediaRecorder.reset();
        Activity activity = getActivity();
        if (null != activity) {
            Toast.makeText(activity, "Video saved: " + getVideoFile(activity),
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        startPreview();
    }
}
```

Comment: Go through  this [http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/android/core/android-video-capture-example/]

Comment: @SanjeevSangral, thank you but the're using a button to start a capture. I want to capture immediately without clicking on a button

Comment: i have made  dummy app same as your requirement  check my ans .

Answer (score 1):

Try this hope it works fine for you.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Uri fileUri;
    public static final int MEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO = 2;
    private static final int CAPTURE_VIDEO_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE = 200;
    public static MainActivity ActivityContext =null;
    public static TextView output;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        ActivityContext = this;

        Button buttonRecording = (Button)findViewById(R.id.recording);
        output = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.output);

      //  buttonRecording.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {

           // @Override
          //  public void onClick(View arg0) {

                // create new Intentwith with Standard Intent action that can be
                // sent to have the camera application capture an video and return it.
                Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_VIDEO_CAPTURE);

                // create a file to save the video
                fileUri = getOutputMediaFileUri(MEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO);

                // set the image file name
                intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, fileUri);

                // set the video image quality to high
                intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_VIDEO_QUALITY, 1);

                // start the Video Capture Intent
                startActivityForResult(intent, CAPTURE_VIDEO_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE);

           // }
       // });
    }

    /** Create a file Uri for saving an image or video */
    private static Uri getOutputMediaFileUri(int type){

        return Uri.fromFile(getOutputMediaFile(type));
    }

    /** Create a File for saving an image or video */
    private static File getOutputMediaFile(int type){

        // Check that the SDCard is mounted
        File mediaStorageDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
                Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES), "MyCameraVideo");


        // Create the storage directory(MyCameraVideo) if it does not exist
        if (! mediaStorageDir.exists()){

            if (! mediaStorageDir.mkdirs()){

                output.setText("Failed to create directory MyCameraVideo.");

                Toast.makeText(ActivityContext, "Failed to create directory MyCameraVideo.",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                Log.d("MyCameraVideo", "Failed to create directory MyCameraVideo.");
                return null;
            }
        }


        // Create a media file name

        // For unique file name appending current timeStamp with file name
        java.util.Date date= new java.util.Date();
        String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss")
                .format(date.getTime());

        File mediaFile;

        if(type == MEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO) {

            // For unique video file name appending current timeStamp with file name
            mediaFile = new File(mediaStorageDir.getPath() + File.separator +
                    "VID_"+ timeStamp + ".mp4");

        } else {
            return null;
        }

        return mediaFile;
    }


    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

        // After camera screen this code will excuted

        if (requestCode == CAPTURE_VIDEO_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE) {

            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

                output.setText("Video File : " +data.getData());

                // Video captured and saved to fileUri specified in the Intent
                Toast.makeText(this, "Video saved to:" +
                        data.getData(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            } else if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {

                output.setText("User cancelled the video capture.");

                // User cancelled the video capture
                Toast.makeText(this, "User cancelled the video capture.",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            } else {

                output.setText("Video capture failed.");

                // Video capture failed, advise user
                Toast.makeText(this, "Video capture failed.",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Really thank you Sanjeev, but the problem is still exist.

In your code you're open an intent of camera but I have to click on the record button. I want to start record immediately without pressing on any button

Comment: go through this [link](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/camera.html) MediaRecorder.start(); will help you

Comment: `MediaRecorder.start` isn't help me, that's the problem (I'm doing this in `Camera2VideoFragment` class). I'll edit my code and add this (google) class

Comment: try this one [link](http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Video_Recording_and_Image_Capture_on_Android_using_Camera_Intents)

Comment: No, there're using button too, I want to start record video WITHOUT CLICK ON RECORD BUTTON

Comment: the function recording call in protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main); recoding(); }   after this no need of button

Comment: protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        startRecording(); // Here

}

Comment: did you try it? if you will I believe (according my attempts) you'll see an exception